# XAMPP and WebMatrix

Tags: mysql, xampp, webmatrix

**Apache Server** and **MySQL** won't start after installed Microsoft WebMatrix 3. I changed Apache Port to **8080/88** and MySQL Port to **3307**. Apache work again but *MySQL doesn't*. If I click the MySQL start button *Windows Notification appear* - Program Name: Net Command and let me choose YES or NO. There's no different clicking YES or NO. MySQL is still deactivate. **How to fix it up**?

```
[mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
[mysql]     There may be an error, return code: 1223 - The operation was canceled by the user.
```

I want to *keep* **XAMPP 1.8.3** and **Microsoft WebMatrix 3** *together* in *Windows 7 x32* and both are work correctly. If I can, and ***how***? Please.

(I tried to upload that screenshot but I don't have enough reputation to upload. Sorry about that, guys.)

Comment: i am also having the same issue

Comment: can you please help me out, you can write the solution here

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Comment: did anyone solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This might be a tough one, although you did provide some good details. If you selected that MySQL should run as a service (from the checkbox in the XAMPP control panel), try deselecting that option and starting it up again - I hope that does the trick, it has for me in the past.